# jquery datatable: Initial sorting by aaSorting for multiple columns not working for ajax data

Tags: sorting, datatables

I have two data tables in my project. First one is taking data from an array in my hand,
**data table #1:**

```
$('#table1').dataTable({
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "iDisplayLength": 25,
  "aaSorting": [[7,'desc'],[2,'desc']],
  "bStateSave": true
});
```

In above table I got the result sorted as expected. But for my second table, which uses an ajax request for data, is not sorted as expected,
**data table #2**

```
$('#table2').dataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: 'a valid url',
  "aaSorting": [[3,'asc'],[0,'desc']],
  "bStateSave": false,
  "iDisplayLength": 25
});
```

I got the column with index 3 sorted but column with index 0 is not sorted for the same values of column 3. Do anyone is facing this kind of issue? Any help or suggestions invited.

Comment: Forum discussion: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/52173/initial-sorting-by-aasorting-for-multiple-columns-not-working-for-ajax-data/p1?new=1

Comment: I think you get the right answer in the forum. Your serverside script must support sorting.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `aDataSort` instead of  `aaSorting` , you can tell a column that it should do a multi-column sort rather than just by itself. - as said over [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/16305/multiple-column-sort-with-server-side) by datatable site admin allan.

For more detail about `aDataSort`, go at [**datatable**](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#aDataSort)

Comment: Thanks @yash. I will try it out ASAP.